# Android.mk file after adding google-ads

Tags: java, android, service, ads, android-source

I am working on AOSP. I want to integrate google-ads into my app. When I am building the project, its showing the following error:
ERROR: The import com.google.android.gms.ads cannot be resolved
import is there is in a java file.

This is my android.mk file.

```
 LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

appcompat_dir := ../../../$(SUPPORT_LIBRARY_ROOT)/v7/appcompat/res
pref_dir := ../../../$(SUPPORT_LIBRARY_ROOT)/v7/preference/res

res_dir := res $(appcompat_dir) $(pref_dir)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android-support-v4 android-support-v7-appcompat  android-support-annotations \
    android-support-v7-preference   \
    googleplayservices

LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(addprefix $(LOCAL_PATH)/, $(res_dir))

LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := Test

LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := --auto-add-overlay
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS += --extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.preference


LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

#################################################################
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := googleplayservices:libs/google-play-services.jar
include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)

# Use the following include to make our test apk.
include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

Can anyone please suggest me what to do?

Comment: You should add updated dependency of Google Play Service in build.gradle file.

Comment: I am working on OS customization. So I am integrating my app into the OS. There is no build.gradle for each app in this case.

Comment: Maybe the google-play-services jar does not contain the ads package?

Comment: It was but android.mk is to be configured accordingly. Issue solved.

Comment: Can you add the solution?

Comment: Can you please update the answer here @KamalAgrawal?